# Returning All Columns From a Query Using PHP's OCI8 Into a PHP Array?

Tags: php, oracle10g, oci8

So I've defined the connection, the statement id and executed the query, now I want to return the results of the query into the an array in PHP.

I'm trying this, but I can't seem to use any of the information in `$rappels` afterwards, what is the proper way to return all of the columns from the query results into this `$rappels` array and then use them?

```
$rappels = array();
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) 
{                       
    $rappels[] = $row['operation_id']['operation_type']['date']['aircraft_fullname'];
}
return $rappels;
```

Comment: Any errors? Is `$rappels` empty after you perform your loop?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the full resultset from a query you use the [`oci_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) function:

```
oci_fetch_all($stid, $rappels);
```

This will populate `$rappels` with an array structured by column, like this:

```
Array
(
    [operation_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            ...
        )
    [operation_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            ...
        )
    ...
)
```

To retrieve the resultset structured by row you would use this code (check the function documentation for the meaning of the extra parameters):

```
oci_fetch_all($stid, $rappels, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW + OCI_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And `$rappels` will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operation_id] => 1
            [operation_type] => a
            ...
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [operation_id] => 2
            [operation_type] => b
            ...
        )
    ...
)
```